# Cast Linq Method Issue

Tags: c#, linq

I an simply trying to use 'Cast' generic method of LINQ as follows :

```
List<string> lstData=new List<string>{"1","2","4"};
var iData= lstData.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Getting Issue ***Specific cast not valid***

Comment: well you can't cast `string` to `int` directly, why would `Cast` method change that fact ?

Comment: @SelmanGenç thanks ,for guiding .. but provide the soluction if possible .instead of downvoting the guys providing soluction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant cast string to integer. you have to convert string into integer. use  `int.Parse` to convert string to int.

```
var iData= lstData.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Comment: @fubo Well, then what is `Convert.ToInt32(string)`?

Answer (score 4):

Cast is not possible from string to int list.
Just `int.Parse` every item in `List<string>` and put it in `List<int>`.

```
List<string> lstData = new List<string>{"1","2","4"};
List<int> iData = lstData.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```